# the space between . and next sentence

Tags: spacing

Why the space between dot and next sentence of paragraph is sometimes like semispace and sometimes space? I want to arrange all as semi space. How can I do it? 
Another thing, when I am using `\section{Introduction}`, it gives me as `1` Introduction but the space between 1 and introduction is bigger than what I need 
 is there anyway to change it?

Comment: Your two questions are not related (it would be better to ask them separately) spacing in a paragraph is flexible to justify the text at the margins so inter word and end of sentence space will typically vary. The space in a heading is part of the heading definition , usually in the document class you are using, like everything else, it can be changed but the details depend on the original definition about which you have provided no clues.

Comment: If I undersand you correctly, your first issue can be addressed by using the `\frenchspacing` macro. (Just write it somewhere in the preamble.) For fine-tuning the formatting of section titles, have a look at the `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `\frenchspacing` (somewhere in your preamble/before `\begin{document}`); it sets the `s`pace `f`actor after punctuation to be the same. From the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co):

   ```
   \def\frenchspacing{\sfcode`\.\@m \sfcode`\?\@m \sfcode`\!\@m
     \sfcode`\:\@m \sfcode`\;\@m \sfcode`\,\@m}
   ```

   In the above code, `\@m` is defined to be `1000`. As comparison, here's the definition of `\nonfrenchspacing`:

   ```
   \def\nonfrenchspacing{\sfcode`\.3000\sfcode`\?3000\sfcode`\!3000%
     \sfcode`\:2000\sfcode`\;1500\sfcode`\,1250 }
   ```

   Note how there exists different (larger) spacing after `.`, `?` and `!` than for `:`, `;` and `,`.
2. Sectional units set their headings in two parts: (1) `<number><space>` (2) `<title>`. The first part is set using `\@seccntformat` which is a macro that `format`s a generic `sec`tional `c`ou`nt`er. Here's the definition:

   ```
   \def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
   ```

   For any counter `<seccounter>`, it calls `\the<seccounter>` which prints the actual counter and then inserts a `\quad`. `\quad` is defined to be `\hspace{1em}`, which is font-dependent. If you want to change this space to something more suitable for you, you can add

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{<space>}}
   \makeatother
   ```

   to your preamble for some suitable `<space>`. If you just want a regular, inter-word space, you `\space` instead of `\hspace{<space>}`.