# Reducing the space between section number and section title

Tags: table-of-contents, sections-paragraphs

I create the fourth-level section title following this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection).

With the below code snippet, the fourth level is created but I want to reduce the spacing between the section number and the section title, e.g., `1.1.1.1   D1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
    {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
    {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % how many sectioning levels to assign numbers to
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    % how many sectioning levels to show in ToC

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{A}
    \subsection{B}
    \subsubsection{C1}
    \paragraph{D1}
    \paragraph{D2}
\end{document}
```

Here is the figure to illustrate my confusion:

[image]

I just want to reduce the space which is represented as the red rectangle.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you referring to the space within the ToC or the actual text? For the latter, see [the space between . and next sentence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/343878/5764).

Comment: Please also tell us which document class you employ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the last length in `l@paragraph` (`l` stands for "list"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{7.0em}{3.5em}}\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % how many sectioning levels to assign numbers to
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    % how many sectioning levels to show in ToC

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{A}
    \subsection{B}
    \subsubsection{C1}
    \paragraph{D1}
    \paragraph{D2}
\end{document}
```

To clarify:

Each header has a `l@` command that appears in `article.cls` (located  in most tex ditros at `texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`). The original values was `4.1em`.

Just before `l@paragraph` you can find similar commands for section (`l@section`) and subsection.

[image]